# How do I prove that the product topology is the unique topology for which projections are well-behaved?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

This is a question from a practice qualifying exam.

Let $X, Y, T$ be topological spaces.
Define $p_X: X\times Y\to X$ and $p_Y:X\times Y\to Y$ to be the projection maps.
Then $f:T\to X\times Y$ is continuous if and only if the compositions $p_X \circ f : T\to X$ and $p_Y\circ f: T\to Y$ are continuous. (I have already proven this).

Prove that the product topology on $X\times Y$ is the unique topology that, for all spaces $T$ and functions $f$, has the previous property.

As shown here: [Product topology on $X \times Y$ the smallest topology when $f(x, y) = x$ and $g(x, y) = y$ are continuous functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706453/product-topology-on-x-times-y-the-smallest-topology-when-fx-y-x-and-g), we know that any topology n $X\times Y$ with the property must at least contain the product topology (just use $T = X\times Y$ and $f = id$). Thus, the only thing that I need to show is that any topology for which the property holds is contained in the product topology, but unfortunately I'm not really sure how to approach this.

Comment: It is the unique *smallest* topology.  It is not unique however: take the discrete topology on both spaces, that works automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, could you elaborate? Edit: See Eric's answer, I'm pretty sure you're off on this.

Comment: Ah, sorry, was going off the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that if you have any topology $\tau$ on $X\times Y$ with this property, then the projections $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are both continuous with respect to $\tau$ (take $T=(X\times Y,\tau)$ and $f=id$).  Now if $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are two topologies on $X\times Y$ with this property, then the identity map $X\times Y\to X\times Y$ is continuous from $\tau_1$ to $\tau_2$ (use the property for $\tau_2$ and take $T=(X\times Y,\tau_1)$, $f=id$).  By symmetry, the identity map is also continuous from $\tau_1$ to $\tau_2$.  Thus $\tau_1=\tau_2$.

Comment: Hi Eric. What's the use of the first part of your answer(i.e. the derivation of the continuity of the projections $p_X$ and $p_Y$)? I feel like the second part of your argument is sufficient enough to conclude the uniqueness. Thanks.

Comment: The second part uses the first part: in order to apply the universal property to relate $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, you need to know that certain maps are continuous, which are exactly the projection maps.

Comment: Ah yeah, you are right. Thanks.